# How can I get the attribute values for all the elements that's in an XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to pull the attribute values for each of the element that is in this XMl file ( XML below). I want the attribute values for the following: type, label, CompTypes, readonly, hidden, and required.

Comment: This is not an xml file, it is an xml schema.  Do you have a real xml?

Comment: Hi @jdweng, No this is the only file I am working with. I need to pull the data from this file only.

Comment: Did you edit the file?  I've seen lots of Xml files with embedded schema.  The schema section specifies the types with no values and the xml section assigns values.  Your Xml file do not meet the normal embedded schema standard.  The schema section is assigning values instead of declaring types.  Then there is no Xml section.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, XDocument.Load(@"D:\New Text Document.xml").Descendants()
            .Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("element", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .Select(x => new CustomElements()
            {
               Type = x.Attribute("type")?.Value,
               Label = x.Attribute("label")?.Value,
               CompTypes = x.Attribute("CompTypes")?.Value,
               Readonly = x.Attribute("readonly")?.Value,
               Hidden = x.Attribute("hidden")?.Value,
               Require = x.Attribute("required")?.Value
            }).Select(x => $"{x.Type}, {x.Label}, {x.CompTypes?.Replace(";", ",")}, readonly=\"{x.Readonly}\", hidden=\"{x.Hidden}\", required=\"{x.Require}\""));
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, if you don't mind, could please put this code in a CS template ? I am trying you steps, but I am seeing many red squiggly lines in Visual Studio. I just want to see if I am missing anything. Thanks.

Comment: Add these 2 include statements: `using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
`

Comment: Hello @Matt, so after getting the data, how can I then output that information onto a CSV file automatically? Is there a way to create a CSV file?

Comment: Try File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv);

Comment: So, would i add this File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv) in the main?The filepath in my scenario would be the D drive correct?